# Divide dataset into n partition

Tags: java, loops, partitioning

Suppose I have an array a. I want to divide it in n partition. How can I perform the for function in Java? I tried this code but in some cases it is wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[] part = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        for (int i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
            for (int j = ((a.length / part.length) * part[i]); j < ((a.length / part.length) * (part[i] + 1)); j++) {
                System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 
3 4 
5 6 
7 8
```

Data 9 and 10 are missing. I do not need an equal size, but at least all data is well distributed. How to modify the for j function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution (very naive approach, not benchmarked or optimised for performance):

```
int numOfPartitions = 4; 
double n = (double)a.length/numOfPartitions;
int start =0;
int partitionNum=1;
while(partitionNum<= numOfPartitions)
  {        
    int end = (int)java.lang.Math.ceil(n*partitionNum);
    for(int k = start;k<end;k++)
      {
        System.out.print(a[k] + " ");
      }
    start = end;
    ++partitionNum;
    System.out.println();
  }
```

First, see what would be the size of each partition (even if it is not integral). We will use it to slice up the array into sub-arrays.

Now, start slicing into sub-arrays from the first element of the input array. We use a strategy of taking the largest integer closest to **(computed partition size * current partition number)** as the upper bound. In this example, we have size = 10/4 = 2.5, so our indices to break into sub-arrays will be 3 (for 2.5), 5, 8 (for 7.5) and 10.

The first sub-array will take the elements from index 0 of input until index 2, since the first computed index is 3. The next sub-array starts at index 3 and goes till index 5, and so on.

This way, we end up with the sub-arrays having number of elements differing at most by 1 from each other.

Note: If we have more partitions than number of elements in input, we can just return the entire array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually my function above is implemented in multi thread manner, that's why I used array part. This elements will be used as number of thread, so that the array can be processed in parallel. Your code seems for sequential manner since variable start and end will change after previous process finished. is there any way to do it in multi thread manner? @shree.pat18

Comment: Each pair of start and end can be precomputed, if you know the input array size. Then you don't need the while loop, instead you can pass the start and end arguments for parallel processing

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to compute start and end. I use ((a.length / part.length) * part[i]) as start and ((a.length / part.length) * (part[i] + 1)) as end, I mentioned above inside for j. But it was not working properly. So my question is how to change my for j function. @shree.pat18

Comment: Thanks @shree.pat18 now I solved the problem based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

### [Guava's Lists.partition()](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava):

```
List<Integer> longList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<List<Integer>> lists = Lists.partition(longList, 2);
lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
```